# Where and how to extract repeated business logic?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, dry

I have certain business logic that repeats throughout my code. Is there a standardized way of separating this out for version 4.2? I know in the newer versions, `Command`s are used for this type of thing. Example of repeating logic:

```
// detach tags
$card->tags()->detach();

foreach (Input::get('tags', []) as $tag)
{
    // existing tag
    if (is_numeric($tag) && Tag::whereId($tag)->exists())
    {
        $card->tags()->attach($tag);
    }

    // new tag
    else
    {
        $new_tag = new Tag();
        $new_tag->market()->associate($market);
        $new_tag->name = $tag;
        $new_tag->save();

        $card->tags()->attach($new_tag->id);
    }
}
```

The simplest way I could do this is create a new class, like `TagManager` and add methods for this logic, like `createTag`, `attachTagToCard`, etc. However, I'm not sure if there is already a "predefined" way of doing this.

Comment: Creating a `TagManager` would generally be a good way to go about this.  I would change it up a little so you pass in the tags to be created rather than grab them from `Input`.  It tends to make it a bit more reusable.  Was there something about this you didn't like?

Comment: @user3158900 Nothing against it. I just didn't know if there was already some predefined place to do this like in the newer versions of Laravel. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repeated code problem can be solved by using traits.
For more information on trait go [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

Create a file called **TagManagerTrait.php** inside the folder **app/traits**

contents of file

```
<?php
namespace App\Traits;

trait TagManagerTrait {

public function createTag()
{
    // your create tag logic
}


public function updateTag()
{
      //your update tag logic
}
```

}

Update your composer.json to autoload this

```
{
    "autoload" : {
        "classmap" : [
           "app/traits"
        ]
    }
}
```

In the controllers where you want to use the repeated code

```
<?php
use App\Traits\TagManagerTrait;

class XyzController extends Controller{

    use TagManagerTrait;
}
```

Now the controller will inherit all the functions of the trait and be used freely.